# Seperate mysql order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that consists of the following fields

`id, date, featured`

featured is a bit which is 0 or 1

I want to order my MySQL table by if it's featured or not(featured = 1) first then I want the rest of the table to be ordered by the date.
I was only able to order it by one or the other.

This is my current SQL statement

`SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY featured = 1 DESC, date DESC`

Comment: Should the date be in ascending or descending order? Is the date column an actual date type column or is it a string type column? Do you have some sample data?

Comment: Sample data expected results would go a long way on this one.

Comment: Your code does what you describe, so the question is unclear.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM listing ORDER BY verified DESC, date DESC
```

Remove the `= 1` from your query

Comment: Im still getting the same results

Comment: Provide the Input and output

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to select items which are verified (`verified = 1`) and then ordered by date (most recent first, which is `DESC`). You probably want:

```
SELECT * FROM listing WHERE verified = 1 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Its featured and i still want the ones where featured is 0 I just want them ordered by the date after all the ones where featured is one